# Docker containers exiting without identifiable cause (Django web application)

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, gunicorn

I've taken over the maintenance of a live web project that utilizes docker containers. Immediately, I've noticed that the web app goes down after a couple of hours, and `docker ps -a` shows me:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                    PORTS                                   NAMES    
9b02f1352f15        nginx:latest     "nginx -g 'daemon off"   9 weeks ago     Exited (1) 14 hours ago   80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8000/tcp   ng01
8079b3d3b398        webapp_web       "gunicorn --error-log"   9 weeks ago     Exited (1) 14 hours ago   8000/tcp                                webapp_web_1
564fe0b72fa6        d0f5f9c3d3a6     "/bin/sh -c 'apt-get "   12 weeks ago    Exited (0) 12 weeks ago                                           modest_perlman
6cddbfcfa8f6        d0f5f9c3d3a6     "/bin/sh -c 'apt-get "   12 weeks ago    Exited (0) 12 weeks ago                                           backstabbing_goldwasser
7460be4f4451        postgres         "/docker-entrypoint.s"   4 months ago    Exited (1) 14 hours ago   5432/tcp                                webapp_db_1
```

Notice the 3 containers that exited **14 hours ago** - those relate to the web app. How do I diagnose/fix this problem? Being a beginner, I'm struggling here. Thanks in advance! Following are some diagnostics I tried to run.

---

I used `docker logs` on the errant containers to see what could be going wrong.

`docker logs 9b02f1352f15` (nginx) is empty.

`docker logs 8079b3d3b398` (application server - gunicorn) shows many incidences of:

```
Exception in thread Thread-725265:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unirest/__init__.py", line 97, in __request
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster/streaminghttp.py", line 142, in http_open
    return self.do_open(StreamingHTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

`docker logs 7460be4f4451` (postgresql backend) shows many incidences of:

```
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-01-22 12:42:46 UTC
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  invalid record length at 0/17AAD28
LOG:  redo is not required
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

---

In case it matters, doing `tail -f docker.log` at `/var/run/upstart/docker.log` gives the output:

```
INFO[0000] Firewalld running: false                     
time="2017-01-23T14:38:47.142345718Z" level=error msg="devmapper: Error unmounting device 3da5c7e87cc8969249d7ed8b15c9cea9296feaefeba62fde534b4c183e4edbd4: Device is Busy" 
time="2017-01-23T14:38:47.142542018Z" level=error msg="Error unmounting container 8079b3d3b3988a793537c4116bd12c70823415cb84068021d25658a316d8f568: Device is Busy" 
INFO[0000] Firewalld running: false                     
INFO[0000] Firewalld running: false                     
time="2017-01-23T14:40:20.694963580Z" level=error msg="devmapper: Error unmounting device 6fd51632808dede3fea81b4f19fb84f1a13d93c38917e2845d0776de6a2ef941: Device is Busy" 
time="2017-01-23T14:40:20.695010680Z" level=error msg="Error unmounting container 9b02f1352f15447acb7669bff918db0eeed58dc832fff565f4b2a4236474db1f: Device is Busy" 
INFO[0000] Firewalld running: false                     
time="2017-01-23T14:41:27.307003457Z" level=error msg="devmapper: Error unmounting device 7c5a35dc9fc1929e57de43f5efc8e05a9442782c7496713d313c95fe62910f7b: Device is Busy" 
time="2017-01-23T14:41:27.307059457Z" level=error msg="Error unmounting container 7460be4f445102274dd4aba4f113db23c17f58b9f771fc5c474d174766ae593c: Device is Busy"
```

---

I also tried `docker inspect` on all three. Following are the results relating to `state` - there seems to be nothing wrong here.

`docker inspect 9b02f1352f15`(nginx):

```
  "State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 1,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2017-01-22T12:42:47.142236155Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2017-01-22T23:38:46.7038628Z"
    },
```

`docker inspect 8079b3d3b398` (application server - gunicorn):

```
   "State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 1,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2017-01-22T12:42:42.602662338Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2017-01-22T23:38:46.5945186Z"
    },
```

`docker inspect 7460be4f4451` (postgresql backend):

```
    "State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 1,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2017-01-22T12:42:34.413283342Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2017-01-22T23:38:46.5102334Z"
    },
```

---

`docker-compose.yml` is simply:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn --error-logfile err.log myapp.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ng01
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Comment: I realize your question is about debugging, and this does not answer it, but if you want the containers to restart themselves so they are not offline, add `restart: always` to the relevant services in docker-compose.yml, they will restart automatically if they crash.

Comment: Fair enough - that at least gets me out of the vicious cycle of manually restarting them. Essentially, I'd be adding `restart:always` separately under `db:`, `web:` and `nginx:` in my .yml file?

Comment: Correct, once per service. That way you can decide to restart one but not the others, etc. There are different policies, see [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restartpolicy). Actually it seems they have started calling it `restart_policy`, at some point.